# Delete Worksheets based on Checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to write a piece of code where someone is able to use a checkbox to choose which worksheets they would like to keep and what they would like removed. Here is what that looks like:

[image]

(currently debating if I should turn this into a userform but i would still be stuck at this point).

What I would like to do is if the checkbox is unchecked (false) on the worksheet called "Setup", delete the worksheet and move onto the next if statement. From the code below, I am prompt with the run-time error '1004': Unable to get the OLEObjects property of the worksheet class. I have checked and the Checkbox name is the same as what I have in my code.

```
Sub DeleteSheetCB()

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup").OLEObjects("CheckBox1") = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Program Information").Delete
    End If
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup").OLEObjects("CheckBox2") = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Spend and Trx Data").Delete
    End If
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup").OLEObjects("CheckBox3") = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Delete
    End If
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup").OLEObjects("CheckBox4") = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TMC Overview").Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

EDIT:
I was able to get this piece of code to delete sheets but if possible, would someone be able to sense check this for me please?

```
Sub DeleteSheetCB()

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup").Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value <> 1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Program Information").Delete
    Else: End If
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup").Shapes("Check Box 2").ControlFormat.Value <> 1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Spend and Trx Data").Delete
    Else: End If
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup").Shapes("Check Box 3").ControlFormat.Value <> 1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Requirements").Delete
    Else: End If
    
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup").Shapes("Check Box 4").ControlFormat.Value <> 1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TMC Overview").Delete
    Else: End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing I'd take from your second code is:

- It will give you a warning before it deletes each sheet
- You'll get a subscript out of range error if the sheet has already been deleted.
- You have to update your code if you add a new tick box.

---

The code below assumes the caption of the checkbox is exactly the same as the name of the sheet to be deleted.

```
Sub DeleteSheetCB()

    Dim chkBox As CheckBox
    
    Dim sMissing As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup")
        For Each chkBox In .CheckBoxes 'Look at all checkboxes in Setup sheet.
            If chkBox.Value = 1 Then 'If it's ticked.
                If WorksheetExists(chkBox.Caption) Then 'Check worksheet exists.
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Turn off warnings about deleting a sheet.
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(chkBox.Caption).Delete
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'Turn on warnings about deleting a sheet.
                Else
                    sMissing = sMissing & "- " & chkBox.Caption & vbCr
                End If
            End If
        Next chkBox
    End With
    
    If sMissing <> "" Then
        MsgBox "These sheet(s) could not be deleted as they were already missing:  " & vbCr & vbCr & sMissing
    End If
    
End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(SheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName) 'Try and set a reference to the sheet.
    WorksheetExists = (Err.Number = 0) 'Was an error thrown?
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Might also be worth mentioning that you can rename your checkboxes:

- Select a check box so the `Shape Format` ribbon becomes visible.
- Click `Selection Pane` under the `Arrange` section.
- A sidebar will appear showing the shapes on the sheet.  You can rename or change their visibility here.

`chkRemoveProgramInfo` makes more sense than `Check Box 1`.

Comment: No problem.  Just thought - at the moment it will give you a message box for each missing sheet.  Better to have one at the end listing all the sheets it couldn't delete.  I'll update the code.

Comment: I have just tried out the code and every time it tries to delete, the chkBox.Caption is always ="".  I followed your steps of renaming each checkbox to their corresponding sheet name.  Do these need to be ActiveX checkboxes rather than form control?

Comment: That's odd.  I'm using the Form Control Checkbox.  Is the `chkBox` variable referencing a control on each iteration of the loop?  Highlight the word, right-click and select _Add Watch..._ to see what a variable holds as you step through the code (or open the _Locals Window_ through the _View_ menu.